# Smallest modern Linux distro for x86 architecture

Tags: linux, x86

I'm looking for small Linux distro like Damn Small Linux or TinyCore. It has to be complete kernel, bash, package manager and networking and nothing else ideally. The two mentioned are not suitable for my use and DSL is outdated.

It has to be able to support 200 MHz + and 256 MB Ram x86 architecture and live boot without install, preferably capable of running entirely in RAM.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can make your own distro to feat your need from DSL or Tinycore , there are both good choises  as starting point.  you mught look at (https://itsfoss.com/lightweight-linux-beginners/) puppy linux may be a good point ... to start from also

Comment: What does it have to do? Does it have to be Gnu/Linux, or any old Linux (e.g. busybox+Linux+nothing else: just the one process). You can go a lot smaller than the ones you name, and the hardware you specify, if it does not have to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alpine Linux is small and can boot from CD or USB medium and run from RAM.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux

https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Installation